# Big O Notation and Derivative for Proof

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Show that $\frac{f(a+h)-f(a-h)}{2h}-f'(a)=\mathcal O(h^2)$ if, on open interval containing $a$, $f$ has continuous derivative up to third derivative

---

By using L'Hospital rule, $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a-h)}{2h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f'(a+h)+f'(a-h)}{2}=\frac{2f'(a)}{2}=f'(a)$

But the question specifically states derivatives up to the third one. How to incorporate the second and third derivative in the proving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply compute the Taylor expansions of $f(a+h)$ and $f(a-h)$ about $a$ and truncate it at the appropriate term to get the desired error.

We have $$
\begin{align*}
f(a\pm h) &= f(a) \pm hf'(a) + \frac{h^2}{2}f''(a) + \frac{h^3}{6}f'''(a) + \cdots\\
&= f(a) \pm hf'(a) + \frac{h^2}{2}f''(a) + \mathcal O(h^3).
\end{align*}
$$ (In this case, we want our truncation error to be $\mathcal O(h^3)$ because we will be dividing it by $h$.)

So, $$
\begin{align*}
\frac{f(a+h) - f(a-h)}{2h} &= \frac{(f(a) + hf'(a) + \frac{h^2}{2}f''(a) + \mathcal O(h^3)) - (f(a) - hf'(a) + \frac{h^2}{2}f''(a) + \mathcal O(h^3))}{2h}\\
&= \frac{2hf'(a) + \mathcal O(h^3)}{2h}\\
&= f'(a) + \mathcal O(h^2).
\end{align*}
$$

Hence, $$\frac{f(a+h) - f(a-h)}{2h} - f'(a) = \mathcal O(h^2).$$

Note that this is a general method to compute finite differences.

**Edit:** If the function is only $k$ times differentiable at $a$, then everything above (except the first line) still holds by Lagrange's remainder theorem.